# Compositing render results over an image viewed with perspective?

Tags: compositing-nodes

Two cubes are to be mixed with an existing background image. The particularities are:

- The cubes receive a colored light, but the background image mustn't be lighted.
- The background image needs some viewing angle correction so that it aligns well with the 3D scene.
- The background image is re-framed, it doesn't correspond exactly to the camera field of view (nor it's perspective angle).

In order to set up the scene I've used an empty with the background image, and aligned everything using the camera view. The rendered image has a transparent background.

[image]

1: Background image -- 2: Final camera view -- 3: Scene set up -- 4: Render result.

The composited image I'm looking for:

[image]

What is the way to obtain that (using Blender 2.79 with Cycles)?
Blender file: [Link](https://nofile.io/f/xZ65btJeTwc/Compositing+2.blend).

Comment: Just to confirm .. you want to adjust the bg image to the 3D render, _not_ the render to the bg image?

Comment: @RobinBetts: Yes, the bg image has to match the render.